# Return changes in a model

Tags: c#, methods, return-value

I have a model with some settings.
How can change some of the settings in another class.

Now I give the model as parameter to a method, change the desired values and return the same model.

```
    public PluginSettings SetDefaultSettings(
            PluginSettings pluginSettings)
    {
      pluginSettings.Minutes = 10;
      return pluginSettings;
    }
```

but is there another way of doing this ?

Comment: What is wrong with the current approach ? You don't even have to return the object if it is `class` (not `struct`), the method can return `void` because the object is passed by reference.

Comment: I have set it to void because of the object passed by reference.